# Delphi: search string with array

Tags: arrays, delphi, search

I need some calculator with Delphi and sometimes my number include `'<'` and `'>'`. I need to store them for after usage. For example:

```pascal
fnc_ProcessNumber('0.320>','100',multiplication)
```

This needs to give this output: `320>`, but this line fails:

```pascal
boolControl := ContainsText(strEnteredResult,[lessThan,greaterThan]);
```

I also try this:

```pascal
boolControl := IndexStr(strEnteredResult,[lessThan,greaterThan]);
```

Here's my code and type.

```pascal
type TMaths  =  (addition,subtraction,multiplication,division);

function fnc_ProcessNumber(strEnteredResult,strProcessedNumber:string;Math:TMaths) : string;
const lessThan : string = '<';
const greaterThan : string = '>';
var
  intIndexCounter,intIndexMath:Integer;
  extNewResult:Extended;
  boolControl,boolLess,boolGreater:Boolean;
begin
  Result := 'null';
  boolControl := ContainsText(strEnteredResult,[lessThan,greaterThan]);
  if boolControl then
  begin
    case intIndexCounter of
      0:
        begin
          intIndexMath := AnsiPos(lessThan,strEnteredResult);
          boolLess := True;
        end;
      1:
        begin
          intIndexMath := AnsiPos(greaterThan,strEnteredResult);
          boolGreater := True;
        end;
    end;
    strProcessedNumber := Copy(strEnteredResult,intIndexMath,1);
  end
  else
  begin
    extNewResult := StrToFloat(strEnteredResult);
  end;
  case Math of
    addition:
      begin
        extNewResult := extNewResult + StrToFloat(strProcessedNumber);
      end;
    subtraction:
      begin
        extNewResult := Abs(extNewResult - StrToFloat(strProcessedNumber));
      end;
    multiplication:
      begin
        extNewResult := extNewResult * StrToFloat(strProcessedNumber);
      end;
    division:
      begin
        extNewResult := extNewResult / StrToFloat(strProcessedNumber);
      end;
  end;
  Result       := FloatToStr(extNewResult);
  if boolLess then Result := lessThan+Result;
  else if boolGreater then Result := Result+greaterThan;
end;
```

Comment: For your next question, please try to isolate a *single* question. For instance, "Given a string S and an array Arr of strings, how do I find out whether or not there exists an element A in Arr such that A is a substring of S" without even mentioning the calculator part.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 32> and not 320>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [`ContainsText`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.ContainsText) clearly cannot be used, since its second argument is a single string, not an array of strings.

And [`IndexStr`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.IndexStr) cannot be used either, since it merely tests whether the text is (exactly) one of the elements of the array; it doesn't do any substring testing. In addition, it returns an integer, the index of the match or -1, so you would need to compare the result against `<> -1` to get a boolean. Or, you can use [`MatchStr`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.MatchStr) which does this test for you.

Finally, `ContainsText` is case-insensitive while `IndexStr` is not. It is better to compare `ContainsText` with `IndexText`/`MatchText` and `ContainsStr` with `IndexStr`/`MatchStr`:

|  | Case sensitive | Case insensitive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Substring found in string? | [`ContainsStr`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.ContainsStr) | [`ContainsText`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.ContainsText) |
| Index of string in string array. | [`IndexStr`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.IndexStr) | [`IndexText`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.IndexText) |
| String found in string array? (`Index <> -1`) | [`MatchStr`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.MatchStr) | [`MatchText`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.MatchText) |

Hence, none of these functions tests (1) if a string is a substring of any string in a string array or (2) if any string in a string array is a substring of a given string.

But of course, it is completely trivial to write such a function. Here's for the second case:

```pascal
function ContainsAnyStr(const AText: string; const AStrings: array of string): Boolean;
begin
  for var i := 0 to High(AStrings) do
    if ContainsStr(AText, AStrings[i]) then
      Exit(True);
  Result := False;
end;

function ContainsAnyText(const AText: string; const AStrings: array of string): Boolean;
begin
  for var i := 0 to High(AStrings) do
    if ContainsText(AText, AStrings[i]) then
      Exit(True);
  Result := False;
end;
```

In addition, since your string array is actually a character array, you can use [`TStringHelper.IndexOfAny`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.IndexOfAny):

```
'123>'.IndexOfAny(['<', '>']) <> -1
```

Comment: And, of course, there are several other errors in your code. For instance, `intIndexCounter` is an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Or maybe you are looking for `var HasMark := S.EndsWith('>') or S.EndsWith('<');` or `var HasGT := S.EndsWith('>');
  var HasLT := S.EndsWith('<');
  var HasMark := HasGT or HasLT;` Or use `Contains` instead of `EndsWith` if that is what you want.

Comment: IndexOfAny did the job. Thanks for advice either @andreas